# Question on Eisenstein Primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I understand that this is the characterization of an Eisenstein Prime:

"An Eisenstein integer $z = a + bω$ is an Eisenstein prime if and only if either of the following (mutually exclusive) conditions hold:

(1) $z$ is equal to the product of a unit and a natural prime of the form $3n − 1$

(2) $|z|^2 = a^2 − ab + b^2$ is a natural prime (necessarily congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo 3).
"

I see how given a prime $p\in\mathbf{Z}$ it follows that there is either a prime element in $\mathbf{Z}[\omega]$ with norm $p$, or $p$ itself is still prime in $\mathbf{Z}[\omega]$.  My question is how do I show the other direction- that any prime in $\mathbf{Z}[\omega]$ is necessarily in one of these two categories.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime in the extension then $N(\mathfrak{p})$ is either a prime or the square of a prime, in the latter case $\mathfrak{p}$ is actually a natural prime.

$\mathfrak{p} \cap \mathbb{Z}$ is a prime ideal say $(p)$. Then either $p$ splits (or ramifies) in the extension so $(p)= \mathfrak{p}\overline{\mathfrak{p}}$ and we have the first case or $p$ remains prime so $\mathfrak{p}=(p)$ and we have the second case.

Comment: I see how the result would follow from this, but is there a nice way to show that the norm of a prime must take on one of these two forms? I apologize if this is a trivial question, I'm new to the subject.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: @shera250 Note the norm of an Eisenstein Prime is an integer, and norms are multiplicative, so you can apply (rational) integer prime factorisation at the level of norms.